# byte array poiner to fixed byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, fixed, unsafe

I'm trying to make pointer to fixed byte array, so I can serialize it. But no matter what I try it doesn't work.

```
unsafe public struct Test
    {
        public byte*[] DataS { get => _data; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        private fixed byte _data[4];
    }
```

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish

```
struct tst
    {
        public byte[] Data { get => _data; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        private fixed byte[] _data;
    }
```

Comment: What JSON result are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just create an expression bodied property to refer to the array.

```
struct tst
{
     public byte[] Data => _data; 
     [JsonIgnore]
     private byte[] _data;
}
```

This will return a *reference* to the actual array. But I would expect manylibraries to also need a public setter. I.e.

```
public byte[] Data {
    get => _data;
    set => _data = value;
}
```

Actual pointers are mostly used when interacting with native code, most other uses has been replaced by `Span<T>`/`Memory<T>`. And I see no reason at all to use pointers for serialization, most libraries should handle arrays just fine.

Comment: This isn't working, already tried that. I know, I have to use them, just because old library I have to use.

Comment: @John Serializing my example struct works just fine for me with newtonsoft Json. If you have some special requirements you need to specify them in your question. But serializing an actual pointer makes little sense since you don't even know how many bytes you should serialize.

Comment: My apologies I forgot fixed keyword in my question, the second code block, was the logic I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: @John that still does not make your example valid, nor would it make any sense. If you want to serialize your struct to json, just use newtonsoft json or system.Text.Json. You reference an 'old library' but no reason why you are using it, what you are using, nor how it could handle pointers of all things.

Comment: The reason why I'm doing this "nonsense" is becouse my JSON output looks like this: "Data": { "FixedElementField": 1}, and need it like this "Data": [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @John I have no idea why you get that result, you need to specify exactly what library and what settings you are using. By default both json.net and system.text.json seem to serialize `byte[]` to a base64 string, I assume this is configurable. If I change the data type to `int[]` I get `{"Data":[1,2,3,4]}`.